# python3: read from stdin and exit on EOF

Tags: python-3.x, eof

I am reading from stdin, and processing each line. Simplified snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, sys, stat

logfile = '/var/log/mylog'

while True:
    with open(logfile, 'a', buffering=1) as f:

        f_ino = os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_INO]

        for line in sys.stdin:

            try:
                if os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_INO] != f_ino:
                    break
            except IOError:
                pass

            f.write(line)
```

How can I exit the script when EOF is received?

Comment: I deleted my answer, I hope you find the issue.

Comment: would this be a good use for the `for/else` statement ? ie, adding `else: sys.exit(0)` to the for loop?